# How can I run a wrapped java application in debug mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging, talend

I know how to start a java application in remote debug mode

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

But what if the application is not started using an explicit "java" command (that I can find)?

Specifically, there's an open source platform (Talend for MDM) that is built on top of Eclipse.
How can I run it in debug mode? Or similarly, how can I run eclipse in debug mode?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I'd like to add to the open source platform and develop some components for it. In order to do that, I'd like to see how the current ones work

Comment: If you are using talend you can debug your applications. Here you have a [page showing the instructions](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/06/debugging-talend-jobs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Fede. However, I'm specifically looking for a way to debug Talend itself, not debug a Talend Job. So what I'd imagine is that I start Talend with a remote debugging session, and then I launch and attach a debugger from Eclipse to it, so I can step over each method one by one.

Comment: I can't remember if the Open Studio shows it but with the Enterprise versions you can see the code that Talend generates from javajet templates and you could simply copy and paste the lot into Eclipse and run that I guess.

Comment: That's true. Worst case, this may be the closest workaround. Thanks for the suggestion, ydaetskcoR